# How to enter duration like (3.00 to 5.00 pm) in a single column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a specific data type for  this purpose or I need to use two different columns eg from_time and to_time  ?

Comment: @dfundako: Rahul can't use the time data type because Oracle doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't have range data types (like PostgreSQL for instance). It doesn't even have a time data type. A time in Oracle always comes with a date. So you need two columns (start_time and end_time) where you have mainly two options:

- use the data type `DATE` and ignore the date part (and you should always set it to the same date, e.g. date '1900-01-01' which you can ensure with a before-insert trigger).
- use the data type `CHAR(5)` and write a constraint to only allow for hours 00 to 23 and minutes 00 to 59.

The latter is a tad clearer in my opinion while the former allows date arithmetic. Make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [Oracle data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012): there is no built-in type to store such an information.

You could of course invent whatever (strange) coding you like to store these informations

```
create table dates as (
                        select date '2017-01-17' + 15/24 start_date,
                               date '2017-01-17' + 17/24 end_date
                        from dual
                     )

select to_char(start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') || ' - ' ||
       to_char(end_date,   'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')               as as_varchar2
from dates

select XMLTYPE('<XML><START>'                            || 
               to_char(start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ||
               '</START><END>'                           || 
               to_char(end_date,   'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ||
               '</END></XML>')                                as as_XML from dates
...
```

but the right way is two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VarChar2() format and separate the 2 date formats using "-", for example you can show it like "01/01/2000 - 02/02/2000". Here is the code to populate the column:

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate+1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ||' - '|| TO_CHAR(sysdate+1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
from dual;
```

Then, you would be able to parse it back to "DATE" format using the folling statement:

```
select to_date(regexp_substr('01/01/2000 - 02/02/2000','^\d+\/\d+\/\d+'),'dd/mm/yyyy') as date1,
       to_date(regexp_substr('01/01/2000 - 02/02/2000','\d+\/\d+\/\d+$'),'dd/mm/yyyy') as date2
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate columns, but can use an `INTERVAL` type for this, with the understanding that it represents the interval from start of the day to the time you want.  Like this:

```
create table matt_tab1 
  ( from_time interval day to second, 
    to_time interval day to second );

insert into matt_tab1 
values ( interval '17:00:00' hour to second, 
         interval '19:00:00' hour to second );

select from_time, 
       to_time, 
       to_time - from_time duration 
from   matt_tab1;

FROM_TIME           TO_TIME             DURATION
---------           -------             --------
+00 17:00:00.000000 +00 19:00:00.000000 +00 02:00:00.000000
```

#### If you really need a single column...

Of course, you can create a custom object type that encapsulates these two intervals, if you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TYPE my_time_range 
  AS OBJECT ( from_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, 
              to_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND );

CREATE TABLE matt_tab2 (a_range my_time_range);

INSERT INTO matt_tab2 (a_range)
VALUES (my_time_range (INTERVAL '17:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 
                       INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND));

SELECT t.a_range.from_time,
       t.a_range.to_time,
       t.a_range.to_time - t.a_range.from_time duration
FROM   matt_tab2 t;
```

You could then also write useful methods on that object type like `overlaps_with(a_range my_time_range)` or `starts_before`, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, the custom object approach doesn't work in SQL\*Navigator 7.1.0, but it works in SQL\*Plus.

Comment: You could even create a function `my_time_range.duration` that encapsulates the calculation